# Type assertion falling on reference / pointer

Tags: dictionary, go, assertion

I am trying to get a map out of the reference and the assertion seems to be failing:

```
session.AddFlash(gin.H{
    "username": username,
    "password": password,
}, "_post")
```

...

```
flashes := session.Flashes("_post")
if flashes != nil {
    flash = flashes[0]
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", flash)
    if post_data, ok := flash.(gin.H); ok {
        fmt.Println("post_data:", post_data)
        data = post_data
    } else {
        fmt.Println("post_data(failed):", post_data)
    }
}
```

However I always get the following output, which the assert fails:

```
*gin.H
post_data(failed): map[]
```

I assume its due to the assertion I am doing so I've tried:

```
if post_data, ok := (*flash).(gin.H); ok {
```

But then I get `invalid indirect of flash (type interface {})`

I have also tried:

```
if post_data, ok := *flash.(gin.H); ok {
```

But that gives me `invalid indirect of flash.(gin.H) (type gin.H)`

Comment: Can you paste the whole related code ? How is flash created and what is it ?

Comment: Change the first print to `fmt.Printf("%T\n", flash)`. This will print the type of `flash` and should guide you to the correct type to use in the type assertion.  Report back with the results if you need more help.  ... or show us the related code as asked in previous comment.

Comment: @T.Claverie I've added more code, flash is gin.H

Comment: @KarrotKake I've added the type its *gin.H

Comment: You're putting the `*` at the wrong place. It should be `flash.(*gin.H)`.

Comment: @JohnSmith thanks if you want to put that as an answer I can accept it. I had tried it but then I got "cannot use post_data (type *gin.H) as type gin.H in assignment" but that was resolved by dereferencing it

Comment: Declare `data` as type *gin.H. It will be easier for us to help you find the problem if you show more code (the declaration of data for example).

Comment: @Gorilla3D I've posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting the `*` at the wrong place. It should be `flash.(*gin.H)`.

Answer (score 0):

Type assertions require the type you want to assert to be of the exact same type of the assertion part.

From your code, `flash` is a type `interface{}`, and the underlying type is `*gin.H` (printed by `fmt.Printf("%T", flash)`). Therefore the assertion should be `flash.(*gin.H)`

Here are a few examples about of to use type assertions:

```
package main

import r "reflect"

type A struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    // No pointer
    aa := A{"name"}
    var ii interface{} = aa

    bb := ii.(A)
    // main.A

    // Pointer
    a := &A{"name"}
    var i interface{} = a

    b := *i.(*A)
    // main.A

    c := i.(*A)
    // *main.A

    d := r.Indirect(r.ValueOf(i)).Interface().(A)
    // main.A
}

}
```